# SVG is not rendering properly on canvas with Fabric.js

Tags: svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have used `fabric.loadSVGFromURL` function for loading SVG image to canvas.
Most of the images are loading correctly on the canvas but there are some SVG images which are not loading properly on the canvas (half of the SVG is loading as black colored SVG).

Following SVG is not loaded properly on canvas:

```
http://dev9.edisbest.com/Bat_B_020.svg
```

Following is the code which I have used:

```
    var src ="http://dev9.edisbest.com/Bat_B_020.svg";
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL(src, function (objects, options) { 
        var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        shape.set({
                          left: canvas.width/2,
                        top: canvas.height/2,
                        scaleY: canvas.height / (shape.height*3),
                        scaleX: canvas.width /(shape.width*3)

                      });
                      shape.setCoords();
        canvas.add(shape);
                      canvas.setActiveObject(shape);
                      canvas.renderAll();
});
```

[this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofhNM.png) taken when above SVG loaded on canvas; there I got unwanted black color which actually not in the SVG.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Fabric's SVG parser. Please file an issue on [github](http://github.com/kangax/fabric.js).

Comment: Thanks Kangax......! for reviewing my question I have filed this issue on github  https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1021  Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue is solved by Kangax.

please check below link:

```
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/1021
```

thanks you so much Kangax....!