# SVG image renders differently on Canvas with FabricJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, fabricjs

While loading a SVG file on a FabricJs Canvas I found out that it was rendering it with different colours than what it was actually designed for.

[This](https://s32.postimg.org/q1dubx105/Screenshot_2016_06_22_11_02_18.png) is how it looks if i open it on browser.
[This](https://s31.postimg.org/otnspzwuj/Screenshot_2016_06_22_11_07_57.png) is how it renders on the canvas.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/rohitarolkar/71bbc6f0e1f43f6590e571e7f5b6668a) is the gist of my code.

I found a similar post on SVG [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287939/svg-is-not-rendering-properly-on-canvas-with-fabric-js) where the problem was solved with removing the fill-rule="evenodd"; however that trick did not work for me.

I am struggling with this for past 2 days. Need a fresh angle on this.
I would really appreciate any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the same id two different paths. Renamed them, works fine now.